Why are French hypocorisms often formed using a repetition when they are a common noun?
I notice that French hypocorisms are often formed using a repetition when they are common nouns. Examples: chienchien, maîmaître, fifille, pépère, mémère. Why?

Because French can!

I would not say often, it's just one of the ways. Hypocorisms often are diminutives (fillette, frérot...),  phrases (mon petit loup, ma petite chatte...) I wager hypocorisms using reduplication are those used by children when they only have a limited capacity of expressing themselves , and just repeat what they are fond of, but this is just a psycholinguistic remark and has nothing to do with French.  English babies also start saying "mama" an "dada "before they can move on to more elaborate language.(By the way, I don't get why the étymologie tag)

@jlliagre English would be so cuddly-cutie if it could; too bad it's just a few teeny-weeny, tiny thingys away from it.

@None I believe *coco, dada, lolo, dodo, bébé, etc. * are as much toddlers attempting to articulate as grown-ups playfully imitating them.

Note, at least in hexagonal France, family names of hypocoristic origine are ultra-rarely, if ever, formed around a reduplicated syllable; the Breton name Colcanap ("hem waster") plays on alliteration rather than reduplication I think. Canada, Antilles, Polynesia,... may be another bunch.

@FrançoisJurain thanks, good point, indeed, that's why I limited the question to common nouns.

First names are not common nouns but are anyway often truncated and reduplicated:. For example popaul, fifi, gégé, jojo, lulu, loulou, lolo, kiki, zaza, mimi and many many others.

@jlliagre good point, I had forgotten about that
